# Get html values with multiple structure and same class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML/JSP structure:

```
<div class="col-md-12 task task-box">
    <c:if test="${not empty task.titulo}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h3 class="task-title">${task.titulo}</h3></div>
        </div>
    </c:if>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <pre class="task-descricao"><c:out value="${task.descricao}"/></pre>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <small class="task-data-criacao">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i>&nbsp;${task.dataCriacao}</small>
        </div>
        <c:if test="${not empty task.dataExecucao}">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <small class="task-execucao"><i
                        class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;${task.dataExecucao}</small>
            </div>
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${not empty task.arquivo}">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a href="${task.arquivo}" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">
                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        </c:if>

        <div class="col-md-3"><a href="#uplaod"><i class="fa fa-dropbox"></i></a></div>


        <div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <small class="task-tag"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i>&nbsp;${task.tags}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will have multiple structures like this one since I'm using `<c:forEach>`. The wrapper class `task`.

How can I get the information such as, `h3.task-title`, `pre.task-descricao` and others when I click on a `div.task` with JQuery/JavaScript?

PS: I'm using `<c:forEach>` to multiply this structure with different inner values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword inside your event handler to access the element which triggered the event. Once you have this element, you can use the [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function to find the relevant elements inside the target element.

```
$('div.task').click(function () {
    var $title = $(this).find('h3.task-title');
    var $descricao = $(this).find('pre.task-descricao');
    //...
    alert($title.text() + '\n' + $descricao.text());
});
```

[Here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/thlabxku) is a live example.

Answer (score -1):

using JQuery:

```
$( "#taskdiv" ).click(function() {
    var title = $(".task-title").html();
    var descricao = $(".task-descricao").html();
});
```

Info about jquery click:
http://api.jquery.com/click/

Infor about jquery selectors:
http://www.w3schools.com/Jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in this way on click event, i'll recive the first value of each class, not the inner values of clicked parent